# inotify inconsistent with devices

Tags: c++, linux, inotify

On Linux, I am trying to detect a bluetooth controller being connected and start reading from it. I know there's SDL to do that, but I just wanted to learn how to do it specifically  on Linux. So I'm using the `inotify` api to wait for the file `/dev/input/js0` to show up. But when I detect the file I cannot open it. I have the following c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/joystick.h>
#include <string.h>

constexpr int NAME_MAX = 16;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    std::string path = std::string(argv[1]);
    std::string directory = path.substr(0, path.find_last_of("/"));
    std::string file = path.substr(path.find_last_of("/") + 1);
    std::cout << "Directory is " << directory << ", file is " << file  << std::endl;

    int fd = inotify_init();

    if (inotify_add_watch(fd, directory.c_str(), IN_CREATE) < 0) {
        std::cout << "Could not watch: " << file << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Watching: " << file << std::endl;

    char buffer[sizeof(struct inotify_event) + NAME_MAX + 1];

    while (true) {

        if (read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) < 0) {
            std::cout << "Error reading event" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        struct inotify_event &event = (struct inotify_event &) buffer;

        std::cout << event.name << std::endl;

        if ((strcmp(event.name, file.c_str()) == 0) && (event.mask & IN_CREATE)) {
            std::cout << "File has been created" << std::endl;
            close(fd);
            break;
        }
    }
    std::fstream file_stream(file, std::fstream::in);
    std::cout << file_stream.is_open() << std::endl;
}
```

If I run it to detect a regular file, it works, it waits for the file creation event, and when trying to open it with a `std::fstream`, `is_open` returns true. But if I run it to detect `/dev/input/js0`, even when the event comes and the file is detected, opening the fstream does not work, as `is_open` returns false. Is `inotify` appropriate to detect device files? If not, what would be the right way to do so?

Comment: Perhaps secret sauce are flags? Straight from libSDL source: https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/c1336b21ed93dcdeaf06503b4bdadd9bd23c44c5/src/hidapi/SDL_hidapi.c#L183

Answer (score 1):

According to [inotify(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html)

> Inotify reports only events that a user-space program triggers
> through the filesystem API.  As a result, it does not catch
> remote events that occur on network filesystems.  (Applications
> must fall back to polling the filesystem to catch such events.)
> Furthermore, various pseudo-filesystems such as /proc, /sys, and
> /dev/pts are not monitorable with inotify.

I would say that `/dev/input/` also falls into this bucket.

I wonder if [udev](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html) could be used: you should get info about the device using `udevinfo -a -p /dev/input/js0`, but also see what events connecting the peripheral generates using `udevadm monitor --environment --udev`.

**Edit**: if you successfuly get an inotify event but can't read the file:

- Did you try reading the file with another simpler program when the BT device is already connected?
- Is there a difference between `fstream::open` and `open` from `<cstdio>`?
- Have you checked the permissions on the device? Also what does `cat /dev/input/js0` produces?

Comment: That makes sense, but in that case, why am I getting the creation event? My problem is not inotify failing to detect the file, but doing so too early, apparently.

Comment: I missed that part. Does `fstream` successfully open the file if you invoke?

Comment: @alf No, file_stream.is_open() returns 0. What is weird is that is does work with a regular file.