Linux get keyboard mouse trackpad activity
I'm looking for a way to detect keyboard, mouse and trackpad activity on Linux. This will probably be a kernel module. I don't care about the details of the input just the fact that something happened. I don't want it to depend on X. From the kernel headers I've noticed that there's a callback method for keyboard input so that doesn't look like too much of a problem.
I've looked at the kernel headers and libevdev but haven't found anything similar for mouse and trackpad input. With an evdev example program that I tried it required the device name in /dev/input that are mostly named event(n). It didn't work with /dev/input/mice. Also, I'm not sure it's a good idea to open a file and keep it open waiting for events?

You may want to explain what exactly it is that you are trying to do. If I am logged in remotely, do you still want to track my mouse? If nobody is logged in, do you want to track the mouse then? Does this help answer your question at all? https://stackoverflow.com/a/222624/

I'm creating a daemon or module that implements keyboard backlight timeout. I have something working as a user daemon but it's not good enough because it has to work before I'm logged in. If I detect no user input for 10s I switch off the backlight. If the user presses a key or touches the touchpad or mouse and the backlight is off it is switched on. This is just an exercise on a personal laptop, I'm not tracking a mouse or getting keyboard input.

It seems that the way to find out what device is the touchpad or keyboard etc is to iterate through the /dev/input/event* files and test the capabilities of each device. It's the same whether using libevdev or sending ioctl's to the driver. The documentation on how to do this is a bit sparse. When I iterate through the event files it comes up with a mouse that doesn't exist and three keyboards. Only one of the keyboards gives out key codes but aat the moment I don't know how to tell which one it is.

In your comment you say that you are simply looking at activity to control a keyboard backlight (please update your question if you have sufficient reputation; my edit queue is full), so I would approach this from user space. I see two options, both based on the system device symlinks setup in /dev/input/. I initially suggested using the links in by-id/ but my laptop keyboard and trackpad only show up in by-path/ so the better approach may be to scan here for kbd and mouse entries, but you'll have to test. According to this answer, cameras will also show up in here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340430/dev-input-what-exactly-is-this
I assume that in your application the keyboard lights go on with any activity on these devices, and after some timeout they go off. Option one would be to open all the relevant files and put them in a select() loop. The command man 2 select will show you an example program demonstrating how to use this interface if you are unfamiliar. If you are less decrepit than me, I believe the poll() interface is preferred these days - and it is event driven; it doesn't actually poll. Read man 2 poll for more details and to see an example.
The nice thing about these two interfaces is that they take a timeout so your program can simply test if the timeout triggered to determine if it's time to turn the backlight off.
Another option would be to use the inotify() system call. This function will indicate which of the file(s) you are monitoring change. This should be more efficient then opening each of the files because you do not have to read the data from the file itself. More information is available in man 7 inotify.
You can see how this function works by installing the inotify-tools package (this is the Debian/Ubuntu name, other distro package names may differ). For instance, the command:
sudo inotifywait -m /dev/input/by-path/usb-*

will watch all of my USB input devices and report when they change. You can use this to test which interfaces you want to monitor before committing anything to code. You could even write your daemon in shell script or python this way, but I'm assuming you're using C to control the backlight already. If not, the commandline program inotifywait comes with its own -t <timeout> parameter which could simplify your logic significantly.
Another thing to note is that these device files may come and go if devices are unplugged or if they go to sleep. If you use inotify() on the /dev/input directory itself you can be alerted of these changes and rescan the entries to know which files to then monitor.
There is some documentation on these interfaces in the Documentation/ folder provided with the Linux kernel sources. You can also find a copy of this file online: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt
As for controlling the keyboard backlight from user space, this appears to depend on your hardware. Based on the answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/760993/how-to-best-override-behavior-of-keyboard-backlight-key-with-new-custom-driver I found that my laptop keyboard backlight is controllable from the files in /sys/class/leds/dell::kbd_backlight. You may want to see if your system has something similar.
If you insist on developing code in the kernel, this post may be of use as well: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747697/mouse-input-from-files-dev-input
Despite my better judgement, here's an 11-line proof of concept implementation:
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
        # wait for event to turn on backlight
        inotifywait -qq /dev/input/by-id/usb-* || break
        echo LED ON

        # wait for silence to turn off backlight
        inotifywait -qq -m -t 5 /dev/input/by-id/usb-*
        echo LED OFF
done


Thanks this looks useful. I was looking through the code for the dell_laptop module because it has a keyboard backlight that works as you would expect and it seems to be receiving a notification. Is inotify() the userspace version of kernel notifications? In /dev/input/by-id there are three devices that all appear to be keyboards. One gives output when keys are pressed and the the rest give out nothing. I already figured out how to identify the trackpad among the /dev/input/event* devices. I think I can probably figure out the rest but it's not straightforward due to lack of documentation.

I updated my answer to include the keyboard backlight. Please accept it if it answers your question. To add one detail: keeping the files open shouldn't be a problem (except you have to handle file closes and reopens on unplug events); and using inotify doesn't require opening any files. I'll add a note about that as well.

I already have a user daemon that switches the backlight on and off by writing to a file in /sys. I'm getting user idle time from X11 but I want something that works before I log on. I've tried poll() and it's no good for this. It returns repeatedly for the keyboard and once the trackpad has been touched. Probably because there's "data to be read". I haven't tried inotify() yet.

The select()/poll() functions are going to return "readable" until you actually read the data. You also said you didn't want to use X. Put your daemon in the systemd startup scripts and it will run at boot. This is easily searchable. For instance: https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd

I had to disable reading because it threw an error. It doesn't look like inotify is going to work either. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71905918/inotify-inconsistent-with-devices. These functions seem to be meant for regular files. I think I've already explained that I have a user daemon that works but I'm trying to create something that doesn't depend on X. If I run my existing binary at boot it will crash because it can't find a display.

Oof. Don't take this the wrong way, but you need to start over. If the commandline inotifywait works on the /dev files, the command works. That's your proof. If you can control the LED via /sys, that's what you do. In the middle is programming. If using inotify, follow the man page. Don't use select/poll unless you know them. You always have to handle read errors. I suggest writing a script because it's easier - you already have the commands, it's just a handful of lines of code. Nothing I said uses X. If you have more specific questions, post the code and the errors you get from it.

inotify() works if I set the inotify_add_watch() flag to IN_ACCESS. With inotify I'm not having to open and read from the device file. libevdev actually names devices as Mouse, Touchpad etc. but I'm not sure how reliable it is. Thanks for the script despite it being against your better judgment.

It sounds like you really want to do this in C, and that's fine. I do hope the PoC helps - I just try to avoid "please do my homework" answers. Using C is more complex but you can then make your program SUID root. You'll be running this from systemd so that's not a big plus though. Good luck!

poll() also works. The problem was the tiny 10 byte buffer size in the man page example. Scripts have their place :)

From a script point of view it should be possible to filter input devices using "udevadm info  /dev/input/event*"

Sure ... it all depends on your application. If I were doing this for my personal use - based on your description - I would just use inotifywait -m, move the mouse or hit a key to see what devices I want to monitor, and use those. There are many different approaches. This may be of general interest to you, selecting randomly from a general search on the topic: https://amsekharkernel.blogspot.com/2017/02/useful-linux-commands-for-your-work.html
